# UIWebview Loading every time while i use UIPageViewController

Tags: uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller

I have used `UIPageViewController` to display several `UIWebView`  in each `UIPageViewController`. The problem is it is reloading every time i change or come back to the same `UIPageViewController`. I want such that if i come back again to the same page instead of reloading the `UIWebView` it should return the same view which it is loaded first.